# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DbTableDataProvider' not found Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, components

I'm integrating a new component called view-components/grids  to Laravel 5.4, 
 trough composer i make installation of 
 composer require view-components/grids
 composer require view-components/eloquent-data-processing

After that i guess i need to add providers and alias in the app.conf , since it's not mentioned in the docs, but which names should i add ?

i get Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DbTableDataProvider' not found

The documentation mentions that it's compatible with Laravel, 
has someone integrated this component grid into laravel, how can i make it work?
thanks in advance.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Red;
use ViewComponents\Eloquent\EloquentDataProvider;
class testController extends Controller
{
public function index(){

$provider = new EloquentDataProvider(Red::class);

$input = new InputSource($_GET);

// create grid
$grid = new Grid(

$provider,
// all components are optional, you can specify only columns
[
    new TableCaption('My Grid'),
    new Column('id'),
    new Column('nombre'),
    new Column('created_at'),

    new DetailsRow(new SymfonyVarDump()), // when clicking on data rows, details will be shown
    new PaginationControl($input->option('page', 1), 5), // 1 - default page, 5 -- page size
    new PageSizeSelectControl($input->option('page_size', 5), [2, 5, 10]), // allows to select page size
    new ColumnSortingControl('id', $input->option('sort')),
    new ColumnSortingControl('nombre', $input->option('sort')),
    new FilterControl('nombre', FilterOperation::OPERATOR_LIKE, $input->option('nombre')),
    new CsvExport($input->option('csv')), // yep, that's so simple, you have CSV export now
    new PageTotalsRow([
        'id' => PageTotalsRow::OPERATION_IGNORE,
        // 'age' => PageTotalsRow::OPERATION_AVG
    ])
]
);

// now you can render it:
echo $grid->render();
// or even this way:
echo $grid;

    return view('test.tabla', compact('grid')); <--- is this right?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [view-components/eloquent-data-processing](https://github.com/view-components/eloquent-data-processing)
 also (more info: https://github.com/view-components/grids#integrations)

Then set `$provider` variable according to the instruction in [here](https://github.com/view-components/eloquent-data-processing#usage) instead of `$provider = new DbTableDataProvider($pdoConnection, 'my_table');`

**Example:**

```php
use MyApp\UserModel;
use ViewComponents\Eloquent\EloquentDataProvider;
$provider = new EloquentDataProvider(UserModel::class);
```

and also add these references

```php
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Input\InputSource;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Grid;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Component\TableCaption;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Component\Column;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Component\DetailsRow;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Component\ColumnSortingControl;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Component\CsvExport;
use ViewComponents\Grids\Component\PageTotalsRow;
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Component\Control\PaginationControl;
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Component\Control\PageSizeSelectControl;
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Component\Control\FilterControl;
```

you can find all the references to the classes within these 2 repositories

1. [view-components/view-components](https://github.com/view-components/view-components)
2. [view-components/grids](https://github.com/view-components/grids)

Comment: hello Ravisha, your post was of much help , i did it as you mentioned, and now i get Class 'App\Http\Controllers\InputSource' not found ,ill update the code above to show the changes made

Comment: add reference `use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Input\InputSource` (https://github.com/view-components/view-components/blob/master/src/Input/InputSource.php) or since laravel has `Request` class you can use `$request->input('page', '1');` instead of `$input->option('page', 1)`

Comment: At last it worked, i had to add this more necessary lines                        use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Component\Control\FilterControl;
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Component\Debug\SymfonyVarDump;
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Data\Operation\FilterOperation;
use ViewComponents\ViewComponents\Customization\CssFrameworks\BootstrapStyling;                        Thanks a lot

Comment: does this grid allows editing? i don't see edit button for a record

Comment: Actually I'm not familiar with this package, but according to the documentation you can't edit the grid.